# Stripping links returned by BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, regex, hyperlink, beautifulsoup

When I use the BeautifulSoup, I get the following code returned from href.

```
"/url?q=http://druid8.sit.aau.dk/acc_papers/kdln4ccpef78ielqg01fuabr81s1.pdf&sa=U&ei=HkNsUauqN_GQiAf5p4CwDg&ved=0CDkQFjAJ&usg=AFQjCNGk0DTzu2K2ieIKS-SXAeS5-VYTgA"
```

What is the easiest way to cut only the "http://...." pdf so I could download the file?

```
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    try:
        href = link['href']
        if re.search(re.compile('\.(pdf)'), href):
            print href
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

Comment: Cut between `?q=` and the next `&`? Shouldn't require a regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How consistently do they come across?

```
href.split('q=')[1].split('&')[0]
```

Would work without regex.  This might also do it:

```
href[7:href.index('&')] # may need +1 after .index call
```

They both seem to work in my interactive terminal:

```
>>> s = "/url?q=http://druid8.sit.aau.dk/acc_papers/kdln4ccpef78ielqg01fuabr81s1.pdf&sa=U&ei=HkNsUauqN_GQiA f5p4CwDg&ved=0CDkQFjAJ&usg=AFQjCNGk0DTzu2K2ieIKS-SXAeS5-VYTgA"
>>>
>>> s[7:s.index('&')]
'http://druid8.sit.aau.dk/acc_papers/kdln4ccpef78ielqg01fuabr81s1.pdf'
>>>
>>> s.split('q=')[1].split('&')[0]
'http://druid8.sit.aau.dk/acc_papers/kdln4ccpef78ielqg01fuabr81s1.pdf'
>>>
```

You can also get there with this regex:

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> re.findall('http://.*?\.pdf', s)
['http://druid8.sit.aau.dk/acc_papers/kdln4ccpef78ielqg01fuabr81s1.pdf']
>>>
```

Comment: They are consistant on the front, but at the end always have either & or %.  However, the natural fileanme sometimes has % character in it.

Comment: @JosephLee - I added a regex choice which also works.  If you can solve it with string methods you'll incur less overhead than the `re` library requires.  Either way, should be doable.

Answer (score 1):

A more pythonic way to do it would be the `urlparse` library:

```
A = "/url?q=http://druid8.sit.aau.dk/acc_papers/kdln4ccpef78ielqg01fuabr81s1.pdf&sa=U&ei=HkNsUauqN_GQiAf5p4CwDg&ved=0CDkQFjAJ&usg=AFQjCNGk0DTzu2K2ieIKS-SXAeS5-VYTgA"

import urlparse
sol = urlparse.parse_qs(A)
print sol["/url?q"][0]
```

Which gives:

```
>> http://druid8.sit.aau.dk/acc_papers/kdln4ccpef78ielqg01fuabr81s1.pdf
```

The synatax is slightly different if you are using Python 3, shown above is the Python 2.7 version. This is *really* nice if you'd like the other arguments as well, for example:

```
print sol["ved"]
>> ['0CDkQFjAJ']
```